# Fatal error: Class not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a model `Admin_Model` under `Application\core` directory of code igniter. I put all basic database operations under it. When I try to extend my models who are under `Application\model` directory, it throws error.

`Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model' not found in <path to root>/application/models/new_model.php on line 3`

Should I miss any configuration?

Comment: submit your full controller and models code

Comment: Admin_Model create inside Model Folder

Comment: Hi @Random I have not used require_once or any other code. what extra info you want? Please specify, I will give you.

Comment: You may need to require the /application/models/new_model.php

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232445/codeigniter-extend-custom-model-produces-fatal-error

Comment: Your class name must be same as of your filename

Comment: Files in core folder need to start with `MY_` as set in `config.php` file. To make what you want, search for Phil Sturgeon's [Keeping it dry](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY/) article, or also you can see [this one](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/).

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka, you are right. when I use My_Model it works, but when I use Admin_Model it through errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for your efforts.
I find a solution.

By default CodeIgniter have a setting in its config file.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

I just replace 'MY_' with 'Admin_' everything works fine.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Admin_';
```

More appropriate solution is

1. Put class file in libraries folder
2. Add following code to config.php

   ```
   function __autoload($classname)
   {
   if(strpos($classname,'CI_') == 0)
   {
       $file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$classname.'.php';
       if(file_exists($file))
       {
           @include_once($file);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

That's All

Answer (score 3):

This may also be helpful, if you still have problems with **__autoload** to use **class from libraries**. it's work for me, when I use class library tobe parent class at controller.

> PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PHP 7

*this is mycode at application/config.php*

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname){
    if(strpos($classname,'CI_') == 0){
            $file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$classname.'.php';
            if(file_exists($file)){
                @include_once($file);
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am having trouble with my facebook sdk integration in CI4, you guys can look at my question and please suggest something you you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401885/adding-facebook-library-in-codeigniter-4

Answer (score 2):

Extending Core Class

If all you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library - perhaps add a function or two - then it's overkill to replace the entire library with your version. In this case it's better to simply extend the class. Extending a class is nearly identical to replacing a class with a couple exceptions:

The class declaration must extend the parent class.
Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with **MY_** (this item is configurable. See below.).
For example, to extend the native Model class you'll create a file named application/core/**MY_Model**.php, and declare your class with:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

}
```

Note: If you need to use a constructor in your class make sure you extend the parent constructor:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good and ok if I name my model `MY_Model` but other than that its not accepting showing error. Even if I declare my model `MY_Admin_Model` also show error.

Comment: Core models extend only existing models, which are placed in folder **../system/core/** - such Lang, Input, Model... Admin_Model is not a core model, therefore it is also error.

Answer (score 1):

I setup my environment on a Windows machine. Then after move to production using Ubuntu, I had the class not found error.

I discovered my files extension were `PHP` (capital letter). Linux is case sensitive, so the file name need to be lowercase `php`.